# Triggering a JS inside JS?

Tags: javascript, html, wikitext

I want to trigger this [JS](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tanin47/wiky.js/master/wiky.js), this JS parses wikitext to HTML, by taking the value from the current text of the wikieditor. To get the current value of wikieditor, I used this `$('#wpTextbox1').val()`

Wikieditor

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given the line `wiky.process_normal = function(wikitext){` in the JS, I'd guess `wiky.process_normal($('#wpTextbox1').val())` should do it.